# Discord bot not joining the voice channel i'm in

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, ytdl

I'm trying to code  my own music bot but it is not joining the voice channel where I'm in.
Everything else is working fine. I think that I should install a specific thing using npm but I don't know if that's right or not, i'm not sure so can somebody please tell me what should I do to fix this problem...

Here's My Code :

```js
    client.on('message', message => {

    let args = message.content.substring(prefix.length).split(" ");

    switch (args[0]) {
        case 'play':
            
            function play(connection, message) {
                var server = servers[message.guild.id];

                server.dispatcher = connection.playStream(ytdl(server.queue[0], {filter: "audioonly"}));

                server.queue.shift();

                server.dispatcher.on("end", function() {
                    if(server.queue[0]) {
                        play(connection, message);
                    } else {
                        connection.disconnect();
                    }
                });


            }
            
            
            if(!args[1]) {
                message.channel.send("You need to provide a link!");
                return;
            }

            if(!message.member.voiceChannel) {
                message.channel.send("You must be in a voice channel to use this command!");
                return;
            }

            if(!servers[message.guild.id]) servers[message.guild.id] = {
                queue: []
            }

            var server = servers[message.guild.id];

            server.queue.push(args[1]);

            if(!message.guild.voiceConnection) message.member.voice.channel.join().then(function(connection) {
                play(connection, message);
            })

        break;
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using the `discord.js` version 12+, in this version the `voiceConnection` property is removed from the `GuildMember` class.

You should try the following -

```js
message.member.voice.channel.join()
```

Comment: It still doesn't join

Comment: if(!message.guild.voice.connection) message.member.voice.channel.join().then(function(connection) {

Comment: It gives me an error on the first connection that's inside the brackets

Comment: try this - if(!message.guild.me.voice.channel)

Comment: But I'll try your new way so i can get an answer for this question

Answer (score 0):

I think that the line code where you define args is typo,
You're trying to define 'args' with a 'substring' method but this is a mistake, try change it to 'slice' , that should fix your problem.
Unless you tried other commands and they worked.

Try change it to that line of code:

let args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(" ");